# Fast multiple copy of img dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have image binary data which was saved encrypted in server side, and I decrypt the data to image binary in javascript. It is actually picture of the user ( like avatar ) so I want to avoid do decryption for same data.

This is something what is in background of my problem.

So the problem is when I copy these elements to multiple doms it is very slow and browser freeze 1 sec when I copy 20 times these dom elements.

Here is how I made img element from decrypted image data.

```
$(imgElement).attr('src','data:image/jpeg;base64,' + sjcl.codec.base64.fromBits(decryptedBin));
```

Then I copy the dom to into another dom to save.

```
$(imgElement).clone().prependTo('#cached_image');
```

Then I restore from cache to another dom like this.

```
$(emptyImgEml).replaceWith(cachedElm);
```

Does anyone has any idea to speedup this code ?

Comment: what is `emptyImgEml` and `cachedElm` ? Not much code shown here to even understand what you are doing

Comment: yes I know.... There are too much code so I have to pick up important part. So `emptyImgEml` is temporary img which is going to be replaced by img dom which is copied into `'#cached_image'`. `cachedElm` is actually the img dom...

Comment: well some pseudo code would help. Nobody can address performance improvements without some visible flow process

Comment: replace "sjcl.codec.base64.fromBits(" with "btoa(", which is orders of magnatude faster